# From RDBMS to Google App Engines High Replication Datastore (HRD)

Tags: google-app-engine, database-design, python-2.7

I have the following relational schema (say MySQL, it's really in my head):

```
Login, Customer, Friendship, Address, Child, School
```

such that

```
Login(username, password)
Customer(id, firstName, lastName)
Friendship(customer_id, customer_id) //many to many
Address(customer_id, street, city, state, zip)
Child(id, firstName, lastName, customer_id, school_id)//each customer may have many children
School(id, name, city, state, zip)// there are many children per school
```

I want to rewrite the schema as a Google App Engine High Replication Datastore (HRD) schema: Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is as far as I got:

```
class Login(db.Model):
 username = db.StringProperty()
 password = db.StringProperty()

class Customer(db.Model):
 first_name = db.StringProperty()
 last_name = db.StringProperty()

class Address(db.Model):
 # what goes here?

class Friendship(db.Model):
 # what goes here?

class Child(db.Model):
 # what goes here?

class School(db.Model):
 # what goes here?
```

I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend using `ndb` instead of `db`. Check out the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) for more info.

It seems like you have a hang of standard string properties, which is mostly what you need.

For the models which reference other models you can use a `KeyProperty` e.g.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Friendship(ndb.Model):
  first_friend = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Friend)
  second_friend = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Friend)
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but your answer looks correct. Thanks.